# Python Basemap: Plot coastlines but dont plot small features

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I am using python basemap to draw the coastline around the United States the the Great Lakes. When I increase the resolution of the map drawn to 'i' for intermediate, it draws lots of small water features. Is there a way to only draw the coastlines around the oceans and great lakes, and not all small water features?

I have this...
[image]

But I want this... No small lakes, but want the coastline and states drawn at higher resolution.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Awh, figured it out...When creating the map you can specify the "area_thresh" so set that to a large number and it wont outline the small lakes. [See Basemap documentation here.](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap)

```
m = Basemap(resolution='i',area_thresh=10000.,projection='lcc',\
lat_0=38.5,lon_0=-97.5,lat_1=38.5,\ lat_2=38.5,\ 
llcrnrlon=bot_left_lon,llcrnrlat=bot_left_lat,\ 
urcrnrlon=top_right_lon,urcrnrlat=top_right_lat,)
```